# x64 SQL Server Detection On Network Instance Names

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, 64-bit, instance

I am trying to retrieve the details of the SQL Server installations on my network. I used both

```
SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers
SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()
```

But it only returns the server name which isn't fully helping me. I need to get the instance names. Using the registry isn't a good way to do it because I am searching my whole network. I searched and some people said that these methods detects only server names for x64 servers.

Is that true? And if so how can I get over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to enable SQL Browser Service as it is used when enumerating servers on the network. For servers with only one instance with the default name MSSQLSERVER, the Instance name will be blank and will not even be needed in the connectionstring.